# Angular 2 - Cannot read property 'x' of undefined in [null]

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm actually learning Angular 2, but I found an error on i'm stuck. I don't know to fix that, can help me with that?

```
EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'specieSelected' of undefined in [null]
angular2.dev.js:21835 EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'specieSelected' of undefined in [null]
.....
```

The files I have are these:

file: navigation.ts

```
import { Component, View, NgFor } from 'angular2/angular2'
import { RouterLink, Location } from 'angular2/router';
import { SpecieService, SpecieModel } from "../services/specie/specieService";

@Component({
  selector: 'navigation',
  providers: [SpecieService]
})
@View({
  directives: [RouterLink, NgFor],
  template: 
  `
  some html tags
  `
    })

export class Navigation{
  public title = 'Rol';
  public home = 'Home';
  public species = "Especies";
  public professions = "Profesiones";
  public talents = "Talentos";
  public about = "Información";
  public contact = "Contacto";

  specieSelected:SpecieModel;
  location: Location;
  constructor(
    location: Location,
    public specieService:SpecieService
  ) {
    this.specieSelected = this.specieService.species[0];
    this.location = location;
  }
  getLinkStyle(path) {
      return this.location.path() === path;
  }
}
```

file: species.ts

```
import { Component, View } from 'angular2/angular2'
import { RouterLink, RouteParams } from 'angular2/router';
import { Navigation } from '../navigation';

@Component({
  selector: 'species'
})
@View({
  directives: [Navigation],
  templateUrl: 'app/views/specie/species.html'
})

export class Species{
  constructor(

  ){
  }

}
```

On the template, i try to access to `specieSelected.name` and is where i get the error.

> {{navigation.specieSelected.name}}

I think i miss something, but don't know what.

Thanks!

Comment: Check whether you have navigation object in your scope. Maybe you have it declared as `Navigation` not `navigation`.

Comment: I do different, my initial approach is wrong, I used RouteParams. Thanks anyway! :)